# 404 error on Google API

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am getting a 404 error on the URL of the Google API that I am using for authentication.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

What am I doing wrong?

I have enabled the API and set up the apiKey and the clientId in the console.

This is my `gapi.js` file:

```
  // Enter an API key from the Google API Console:
  //   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
  var apiKey = '<removed>';
  // Enter the API Discovery Docs that describes the APIs you want to
  // access. In this example, we are accessing the People API, so we load
  // Discovery Doc found here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/
  var discoveryDocs = ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"];
  // Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google API Console:
     https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<removed>
  // In your API Console project, add a JavaScript origin that corresponds
  //   to the domain where you will be running the script.
  var clientId = '<removed>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  // Enter one or more authorization scopes. Refer to the documentation for
  // the API or https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing
  // for details.
  var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform';
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
  var editNav = document.getElementById('edit');
  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API client and auth2 library
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: apiKey,
        discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: scopes
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
  }
  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      mainDiv.style.display = 'block';
      editNav.style.display = 'block';
      makeApiCall();
    } else {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
      mainDiv.style.display = 'none';
      editNav.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }
  function handleSignoutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    var loggedin = document.getElementById("loggedinuser");
    loggedin.parentNode.removeChild(loggedin);
    var userStatus = document.getElementById("user_status");
    userStatus.parentNode.removeChild(userStatus);
  }
  // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
  function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.people.people.get({
      'resourceName': 'people/me',
      'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names,person.emailAddresses'
    }).then(function(resp) {
        //console.log(resp.result);
        var name = resp.result.names[0].givenName;
        var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0].value;
        authorizeButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<span id="loggedinuser" rel="' + email + '">Logged in as ' + name + '</span>');
        var permittedUsers = [];

        var accessLevels = document.getElementsByClassName('access');
        for (var c=0, len=accessLevels.length; c<len; c++){
            permittedUsers.push(accessLevels[c].getAttribute('rel'),accessLevels[c].getAttribute('id'));
            var status = accessLevels[c].childNodes[0].textContent;
            if(status == 'Admin' && (accessLevels[c].getAttribute('rel') == email || accessLevels[c].getAttribute('id') == email)) {
                signoutButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<span id="user_status" rel="Admin">[Admin]</span>');
            } 
        }
        if(permittedUsers.includes(email)) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            mainDiv.style.display = 'none';
            editNav.style.display = 'none';
            mainDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p id="unauthorised">You are not authorised to view this page.</p>');
            setTimeout(function(){
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                var notAuth = document.getElementById("unauthorised");
                unauthorised.parentNode.removeChild(unauthorised);
                signoutButton.click();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
  }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<header class="header" role="banner">
    <section id="login" class="right">
        <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Log in</button>
        <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Log out</button>
    </section>
    <div id="title" class="sitename">
        <h1>app title</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

and at the end of the page:

```
<script src="js/gapi.js"></script>
<script async defer src="js/api.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

Comment: which is the URL which is returning 404?

Comment: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.r1R9PSUeec4.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP6wF9UoDJJanJeCzehWQM8olqVdw/cb=gapi.loaded_0